# Extract dates from a table - R

Tags: r, function, datatables

For example: If I do a table with the variables "X1" and "X2", and I need to take only the first column from the table and put it into a new data frame with their respective names in columns, and index.:

[image]

¿How can I create a function for do that?

Thanks you!

Comment: Provide the logic behind the calculation and a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput` and show expected output based on that.

Comment: Solution:    t(t(df1)[1,])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what you are looking for something like this?

```
df1 = data.frame(Yes=c(0.38, 0.34), No=c(0.62, 0.66))
rownames(df1) = c("Man", "Woman")
df1
##        Yes   No
## Man   0.38 0.62
## Woman 0.34 0.66

df2 = t(df1)
df2
##      Man Woman
## Yes 0.38  0.34
## No  0.62  0.66

df2[1,]
##  Man Woman 
## 0.38  0.34
```

Comment: Yes, only that in the final code: t(df2[1,])    Thanks you!.  In one line:     t(t(df1)[1,])